# Taking up maximum space inside a box before wrapping?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I need to display a box (position absolute) above my page when clicking on some button designed, inside this box will be a list of "tags" which should be displayed in a row.
But my problem is that I cannot manage to make the tags wrap properly, taking the maximum space of the box. I want to display as many tags as possible in a single row.

Any idea if this is possible ?

https://jsfiddle.net/e18d2ajh/

```css
.vectors {
  display: inline-flex;
  min-width: 20vw;
  max-width: 50vw;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
  
.vector {
  display: flex;
  padding: .35rem;
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  margin-right: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<h5>
  with few boxes
</h5>
<div class="vectors">
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
</div>

<h5>
  with many boxes
</h5>
<div class="vectors">
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `flex-wrap` property to wrap contents to next line

```
.vectors {
  ...
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  ...
}
```

```css
.vectors {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-width: 20vw;
  max-width: 50vw;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
  
.vector {
  display: flex;
  padding: .35rem;
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  margin-right: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<h5>
  with few boxes
</h5>
<div class="vectors">
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
</div>

<h5>
  with many boxes
</h5>
<div class="vectors">
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set `max-width:max-content` on `.vectores` with `flex-wrap:wrap` and it would do the trick, like so:

```css
.vectors {
  display: inline-flex;
  min-width: 20vw;
  max-width: max-content;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
   /* lines I added */
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  gap:.5rem;
}
  
.vector {
  display: flex;
  padding: .35rem;
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
}
```

```html
<h5>
  with few boxes
</h5>
<div class="vectors">
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
</div>

<h5>
  with many boxes
</h5>
<div class="vectors">
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
  <div class="vector">
    Random text
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `flex-wrap: wrap` for `.vectors` and a `flex-grow: 1` for `.vector` so the children occupy empty space left in the row after wrapping. Note, that might look ugly for the last row, solution is using pseudo element. Summary:

```
.vectors {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.vectors::after {
  content: '';
  flex: 100 0 0;
}
.vector{
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/JaredSpb/pen/ZEvJbEL)